# AJAX .Beginform for each panel bar item in telerik mvc panelbar

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have ascenario like I have to place each of panel bar items into a seperate ajas.beginform. All the panel bar items were came through model binding.How can I solve this issue???

Regards
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Yo
It seems you need to add form separately for each of your panelbar items - because if you surround the whole PanelBar - all the inputs from the other (even hidden/closed) items will be validated/submitted along with the inputs in the current opened item.

Comment: Thats the problem which I am facing i.e. I don't know how to surround each panel bar item with individual form. Could you please help me out in this